Explicit isomorphism between A1-module
https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~cschnell/mat615/
In lecture 1, example 1.6
I can't even prove that the two module are isomorphic.
Firstly I don't understand how this matrice is a morphism of A1-module since \partial isn't commitative.

One should post their questions explicitly and not only point to somewhere. Not to mention that the exact same question is posted from another account (possibly you) a day prior.

No, that's not me, I saw it after. I'm gonna to change my post soonly. I still let my questions because he is a step further (apparently)  in the resolution.
